# Android studio Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073741818 (0xC0000006)

Tags: android, android-emulator, exit-code

I got this message, my emulator stopped working.

I already tried:

- deleting some devices
- increasing emulator ram size
- updating android studio
- removing and adding HAXM installer

Does anyone know to to solve this?

Comment: try graphics options with Hardware - GLES 2.0

Comment: only re-installing android studio worked for me

Comment: Good... that was a sure things.. but sometime we try to do it right in the right way. good luck